# WPF Image update

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I am having some problems with WPF, and I was wondering if anyone knew what I should try next. So essentially I have a processing window, that is bound to a list of strings and each gets an Image in a Listbox.

The Code I have for it so far is as follows.

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  Margin="36,100,320,100"  SelectedIndex="0" Panel.ZIndex="1" MouseDoubleClick="MyListBox_MouseDoubleClick">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="checkmark" UriSource="Images/checkmark.gif" />
            <BitmapImage x:Key="failure" UriSource="Images/red-x.gif" />
            <BitmapImage x:Key="processing" UriSource="Images/processing.gif" />
            <BitmapImage x:Key="white" UriSource="Images/white.gif" />
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{DynamicResource  white}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I have tried following multiple online articles but I can't seem to be able to change my resource from white to any of the other keys. So I think my next step is to point the dynamic resource to a class that determines the status of each object, but I can't seem to get it to update the images whatsoever.

I have tried
`MyListBox.SelectedItem = MyListBox.FindResource("checkmark");
            MyListBox.InvalidateArrange();
            MyListBox.UpdateLayout();`

and a bunch of others but it didn't seem to do much. 
I am new to WPF, so I apologize for the newbie question but any help or nudges in the right direction would be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `DataTrigger` or `Trigger` on the `DataTemplate` to change the image source. If you use a `DataTrigger` then you'll need another property to hold the name of the image you want to show, along with the text to be bound. For example:

```
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <BitmapImage x:Key="checkmark" UriSource="Images/checkmark.gif" />
                    <BitmapImage x:Key="failure" UriSource="Images/red-x.gif" />
                    <BitmapImage x:Key="processing" UriSource="Images/processing.gif" />
                    <BitmapImage x:Key="white" UriSource="Images/white.gif" />
                </StackPanel.Resources>
                <Image x:Name="image" Source="{StaticResource  white}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />                    
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="image" Value="{StaticResource checkmark}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ImageToShow}" Value="failure">
                    <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="image" Value="{StaticResource failure}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
```

For more info, take a look at the [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Happy to help. I know how it can be frustrating when starting a new language/framework.